# Modus Tollens and Limit Definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logic

In intro Real Analysis,limits at $c$ are proved in reverse order of the definition. You want to find a $\delta$ so that $|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. To find that $\delta$, you usually work in the opposite direction. Assume $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. By algebraic manipulations deduce a minimum of $|x-c|$ in terms of $c$, and $\epsilon$. Then chose $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ less than that minimum. Finally demonstrate that if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

I was wondering if you could cut the work in half with Modus Tollens.

The definition is $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ so that $ |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Modus Tollens would have $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-L|\ge \epsilon \implies |x-c|\ge\delta$

I find this variation more intuitive and more suggestive of the proof process. It has potential for cutting the work in half, yet it doesn't seem to appear in text books. Is there a reason to avoid it?

EXAMPLE

Suppose you want to prove $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{x+1}=1/2$.

METHOD A:

$|\frac{1}{x+1}-1/2|=|\frac{1-x}{2(x+1)}|$

We want $|\frac{1-x}{2(x+1)}|<\epsilon$. If we restrict $x\in [0,2]$ the minimum of $2\epsilon(x+1)$ is $2\epsilon$. So we are motivated to let $\delta=$ min ( 1,$2\epsilon$).

$|x-1|<2\epsilon\implies 2-2\epsilon<x+1<2+2\epsilon\implies \frac{1}{2}(1-\epsilon)<\frac{1}{1+x}<\frac{1}{2}(1+\epsilon)$

$\implies -\epsilon/2<\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}<\epsilon/2$

So the chosen value of $\delta$ indeed yields the result.

METHOD B

Suppose $|\frac{1-x}{2(x+1)}|\ge \epsilon$

Then $|x-1|\ge  2(x+1)\epsilon$ force $|x-1|<1$, as above,  then the minimum value on the right is $2\epsilon$, thus $|x-1|>2\epsilon$.

We have proven $|f(x)-L|\ge \epsilon \implies |x-c|\ge2\epsilon$

By Modus Tollens then $|x-c|< 2\epsilon\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

So the existence of the minimum alone proves the limit. No need to formally prove $|x-c|<\delta \implies ...$

The methods are similar. In the first method, you do the scratch work, then prove the deduced value of $\delta$ works. In the second method, the scratchwork itself is the proof.

Comment: Your method would actually be this:  Let $\epsilon>0$.  I will find a number $\delta>0$ and *I will show that any value of $x\not=c$ in the domain of $f$ with the property that $|f(x)-L|\geq \epsilon$  must satisfy $|x-c|\geq \delta$.*  How is that different or easier than finding a $\delta>0$ so that  *for all values of $x$ in the domain of $f$ for which $0<|x-c|<\delta$ we must have* $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$?  Maybe include an example that you think illustrates this?  Include some computations  that make your point.  It seems simply saying the same thing and doesn't likely make it easier.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, in the usual way, you first start with an expression in terms of the function and epsilon, then proceed to an expression of $|x-c| < g(\epsilon)$. Then let $\delta= h(\epsilon)$ where $|h|<|g|$. Then you prove   $|x-c|<h(\epsilon) \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. So first you find $\delta$, then you verify it. By what I'm talking about, also one deduces an $\epsilon$ from $\delta$, but then you are done. The existence of the delta alone establishes the proof, no need to verify that  $|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: Amusingly/interestingly, the method used, as you describe, is in fact what the ancient greeks called "Analysis". As Pappus wrote, "Now analysis is the path from what one is seeking, as if it were established, by way of its consequences, to something established by synthesis." Paraphrased by Victor Katz in "A History of Mathematics", 3rd edition, as: "According to Pappus, then, to solve a problem or prove a theorem by analysis, begin by assuming what is required, then consider the consequences flowing from it until a result is reached that is known to be true or 'given'."

Comment: (cont) The process would then continue by trying to use that path to derive a synthetic proof, that is one that proceeds from the 'true' or 'given' to the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment)

Of course one can prove a proposition by contrapositive.

I think you overestimate the "savings". Usually, the chain of reasoning that leads from $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$ to $0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta$ is via equivalences/biconditionals, so that one does not need to "unwound" the process to get to the valid result, any more than most (but not all) methods of solving an equation by algebraic manipulation (which technically are also a kind of 'analysis' in the sense of Pappus).

However, I would point out that the standard definition accurately captures the intuition of the meaning of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$, while the contrapositive, although logically equivalent, runs into the [Black Raven paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox). Essentially we are saying "anything that does not land close to $L$ was not close to $a$ to being with", and that really sounds like "every non-black object is a non-raven." It seems somewhat unsatisfying, even if it is logically equivalent.

Your example is eliding some of the difficulties in the second method. I think that in the end, you would end up with a similar-length proof if written out in full.

Comment: I'll comment that even if the chain of reasoning is not entirely equivalences/biconditionals, the exceptions are generally backwards conditionals. Having carefully recorded all the conditionals, as the OP says, "the scratchwork itself is [still] the proof".

Comment: Excellent point about the Raven Paradox! Can you elaborate on missing detail in the second method?

Comment: @TurlocTheRed: You go straight from $|\frac{1-x}{2(x+1)}|\geq \varepsilon$ to $|x-1|\geq\varepsilon 2(x+1)$. You need to consider the sign of $x+1$ before you drop the absolute value bars, which you did not do. And, also, $|a|\geq b>0$ is equivalent to $a\geq b$ *or* $-a\leq -b$, so one needs to either explain why only one of the inequalities needs to be considered, or consider them both. So there are some words that need to be said there, which are comparable to the considerations restricting $x$ to $[0,2]$ in the "first method". So I don't think you "save" that much, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake actually. When one considers the limit of function $f(x)$ at point $a$ the $f(x)$ may not be defined at $a$, that is why we need to take the deleted neighborhood, i.e. the correct definition would be $$\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ \forall x\in D(0<|x-a|<\delta) \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon ,$$ where $D$ is the domain of $f(x)$.